# Freezing output after running numpy.random.randint() in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, freeze

I've used numpy.random.randint(lower limit, upper limit, size) to make a 2D array with random numbers within the given range. Now I want to freeze this randomly generated array for the follow up steps. So that the numbers don't change every time I run the entire script. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you just clone/copy it when deriving from it and leave the original untouched.

Comment: @RandomDavis it will takes memory, instead we can use `seed` for random function.

Answer (score 3):

Set a seed so that the random numbers generated are same every time you run it.

```
numpy.random.seed(0)
```

[Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html)

Answer (score 1):

By seeding `random` by hand you can get the same random number whenever you call it.
You can seed the `random()` function using `seed()` function. The input is the seed and the same seed input will result the same output.

```
from numpy import random

random.seed(1)
first = random.randint(10)

random.seed(1)
second = random.randint(10)
```

In this code both `first` and `second` will be same.